# Delete records from parent table and child table in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I want to delete record from table with foreign key.
Table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
`employeeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`reportsTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`jobTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`employeeNumber`),
KEY `reportsTo` (`reportsTo`),
KEY `officeCode` (`officeCode`),
CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reportsTo`) REFERENCES   `employees` (`employeeNumber`),
CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`officeCode`) REFERENCES `offices` (`officeCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Second table:

```
Create Table">CREATE TABLE `offices` (
`officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`postalCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`territory` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`officeCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'm facing this error:

> delete from offices where officeCode=7    Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`classicmodels`.`employees`, CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`officeCode`) REFERENCES `offices` (`officeCode`))  0.093 sec

Answer (score 1):

You have one option to delete child table entry first then after delete to master table. like this

```
delete from employees where officeCode=7
delete from offices where officeCode=7
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `employees.officeCode` is declared as a foreign key to `offices.officeCode`, all office codes that are used in the `employees` table have to exist in the `offices` table. You can't delete an office if there are any employees in that office.

You either have to delete those employees first, or you can tell MySQL to do this automatically by adding the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option to the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

If you allow `employees.officeCode` to be `NULL`, you could also use `ON DELETE SET NULL` to leave the employees there, but set their `officeCode` to `NULL`.